# Change models with function in Django

Tags: python, django

My app has a few buttons on a page. Currently the buttons make an ajax call and start a function in views.py. The function runs and returns some data to the user. I now want to function to run and make changes to objects in the model. How do I do this?

models.py

```
class Stream(models.Model):
    step = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the first Django App tutorial? It covers this pretty well, especially the last big block of code interaction at the bottom of the page. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [django app tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). You can create or modify model objects as given below

```
from myapp.models import Stream

#To create object
Stream.objects.create(
                        city = 'Chennai',
                        ...
                     )

#To get a single object with a unique value
Stream.objects.get(id = 1)

#To update retrieved object
some_variable = Stream.objects.get(id = 1)
some_variable.city = 'Chennai'
some_variable.save()

#To filter objects with given value
Stream.objects.filter(city = 'Chennai')

#To update filtered objects
Stream.objects.filter(city = 'Chennai').update(country = 'India')
```